# Unexpected output in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix M

```
type(M) = numpy.ndarray
M.shape = (500,500)
```

and an array of 100 values

```
arr = numpy.arange(100)
```

I would like to multiply a matrix M shaped `(500,500)` by each value in `arr`. That is, each matrix entry is multiplied by a value in `arr`, and the resulting output would be an array of 100 matrices.

For each value in `arr`, multiply this value by the matrix, and create an array of the result, i.e. `[M1 M2 ... M99 M100]`.

I would code this as

```
import numpy as np

for i in arr:
    x = np.asarray( i * M)
```

I would expect the result `x` to be an array like `[M1 M2 ... M99 M100]`, an array of 100 matrices shaped 500 by 500.

However, the above code only outputs one matrix.

How can I change this?

Comment: Well I don't see where you're creating an array of np arrays, you just keep overwriting `x` with your new array

Comment: try `x = [M * a for a in arr]`

Answer (score 1):

Each step of your loop overrides `x`. If you want to create a 3-dimensional array `(500,500,100)`, you can do so in several ways:

Broadcasting (probably the most efficient):

```
>>> res = M[:, :, None] * arr[None, None, :]
>>> res.shape
(500L, 500L, 100L)
```

Creating an output array and populating it:

```
>>> res = np.empty((500, 500, 100))
>>> for i in arr:
...     res[:, :, i] = M * i
```

Or creating a list of matrices (although direct array conversion will make it `(100, 500, 500)`.

```
>>> res = [M * i for i in arr]
```